# creating new column based on the fact whether at least 1 of multiple columns contains value from the list (Python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column which will have True/Falses or 1/0 based on the fact whether at least one of the N columns contains values from the list

I do it in the following way

```
list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
df['new'] = df['One'].isin(mylist) | df['Two'].isin(mylist).... |df['N'].isin(mylist)
```

Is there a faster way to write condition to evaluate that I have "True" in a new column if at least one the N columns contains a value?

I tried to do

```
cols = ['One',...'N']
df['new'] = df[cols].isin(mylist)
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if at least one `True` per row:

```
df['new'] = df[cols].isin(mylist).any(axis=1)
```